# AES Encryption and key storage?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

A few years ago, when first being introduced to ASP.net and the .NET Framework, I built a very simple online file storage system.
This system used Rijndael encryption for storing the files encrypted on the server's hard drive, and an HttpHandler to decrypt and send those files to the client.

Being one of my first project with ASP.net and databases, not understanding much about how the whole thing works (as well as falling to the [same trap described by Jeff Atwood on this subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001267.html)), I decided to store freshly generated keys and IVs together with each file entry in the database.

To make things a bit clearer, encryption was only to protect files from direct access to the server, and keys were not generated by user-entered passwords.

My question is, assuming I don't want to keep one key for all files, how ***should*** I store encryption keys for best security? What is considered best practice? (i.e: On a different server, on a plain-text file, encrypted).

Also, what is the initialization vector used for in this type of encryption algorithm? Should it be constant in a system?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keys should be protected and kept secret, simple as that. The implementation is not. Key Management Systems get sold for large amounts of money by trusted vendors because solving the problem is **hard**.

You certainly don't want to use the same key for each user, the more a key is used the "easier" it comes to break it, or at least have some information leaks. AES is a block cipher, it splits the data into blocks and feeds the results of the last block encryption into the next block. An initialization vector is the initial feed into the algorithm, because at the starting point there is nothing to start with. Using random IVs with the same key lowers the risk of information leaks - it should be different for every single piece of data encrypted.

How you store the keys depends on how your system is architected. I've just finished a KMS where the keys are kept away from the main system and functions to encrypt and decrypt are exposed via WCF. You send in plain text and get a reference to a key and the ciphered text back - that way the KMS is responsible for all cryptography in the system. This may be overkill in your case. If the user enters a password into your system then you could use that to generate a key pair. This keypair could then be used to encrypt a key store for that user - XML, SQL, whatever, and used to decrypt each key which is used to protect data.

Without knowing more about how your system is configured, or it's purpose it's hard to recommend anything other than "Keys must be protected, keys and IVs must not be reused."

Comment: Minor observation: "AES is a block cipher, it splits the data into blocks and feeds the results of the last block encryption into the next block." You're describing [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) *a* method to use AES safely. There are other secure solutions – not all requiring an initialization vector.

Comment: Keys must be protected, but where? If my app encrypts files, and each encrypted file uses its own generated key, and key/fileId pairs are stored in a "keystore" (db/json/xml/txt/blob/...), and the keystore is encrypted using yet another key. Then where do I stick the keystore key? Assuming the en/decryption is an automated app process where there's no user entered passpharase to convert.

Answer (score 6):

There's a very good article on this one at http://web.archive.org/web/20121017062956/http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoCreditcard.html which covers the both the IV and salting issues and the problems with ECB referred to above.

It still doesn't quite cover "where do I store the key", admittedly, but after reading and digesting it, it won't be a huge leap to a solution hopefully....

Comment: 2 year old answer and a domain I don't control.  Time to use the Internet Archive Wayback Machine....

Comment: For the lazy ones - http://web.archive.org/web/20121017062956/http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoCreditcard.html

Comment: No harm, no foul - hopefully the archive link helps folk out :-)

Answer (score 3):

As a pretty good soltution, you could store your Key/IV pair in a table:

```
ID                    Key           IV
skjsh-38798-1298-hjj  FHDJK398720== HFkjdf87923==
```

When you save an encrypted value, save the ID and a random Salt value along with it.

Then, when you need to decrypt the value, lookup the key/iv pair using the id and the salt stored with the data.

You'd want to make sure you have a good security model around the key storage.  If you went with SQL server, don't grant SELECT rights to the user that accesses the database from the application.  You wouldn't want to give someone access to the whole table.

Comment: This is a very good solution if you define the SQL server itself as inherently secure and storing the keys in it meets your requirements of security. This could be taken further by enabling transparent data encryption on the sql server to prevent an attack where someone copies the DB off the server, or physically takes the hard drives to bypass all software access controls.

Answer (score 0):

What if, you simply just generated a key for each user, then encrypted it with a "master key"? Then, make sure to have random ivs and as long as you keep the master key secret, no one should be able to make much use of any amount of keys. Of course, the encryption and decryption functions would have to be server-side, as well as the master key not being exposed *at all*, not even to the rest of the server. This would be a decent way to go about it, but obviously, there are some issues, namely, if you have stored your master key unsafely, well there goes your security. Of course, you could encrypt the master key, but then your just kicking the can down the road. Maybe, you could have an AES key, encrypted with a RSA key, and the RSA key is then secured by a secret passprase. This would mitigate the problem, as if you have a decent sized RSA key, you should be good, and then you could expose the encryption functions to the client (though still probably shouldn't) and since the key encryption uses a public key, you can have that taken. For added security, you could cycle the RSA key every few months or even weeks if need be. These are just a few ideas, and I know that it isn't bulletproof, but is more secure than just stuffing it in a sql database.