# Node.js aes-256-cbc in Java

Tags: java, aes, cbc-mode

How could I implement the following Node.js function in Java?

```
function encrypt(text)
{
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc','my-password')
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}
```

I've read that crypto derives the key and iv from password but I don't know how to do that with Java.

Thanks.

Comment: So, is your question really which Java library to use to do AES encryption?

Comment: @uvesten I'm using javax.crypto and BouncyCastle. Do you know another one?

Comment: Why was my post downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it is recommend to use an [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for the AES crypto, this makes the same plaintext look different when encrypting, but only if you use a non-static IV.

There is some question/answer pair that could match your search: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example)

Ohterwise this is the first thing I found on google, maybe it helps you: [click](https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364)

Oh and this might help you with possible security issues: [click](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/secure-aes-encryption-and-decryption-in-android)

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a JavaScript example, I will remove it now. But the links aren't helpful?

Comment: MaximilianWalter Thank you for your answer. My problem is that we have a lot of passwords generated by crypto so we need to implement the same algorithm with Java for compatibility reasons. However, I don't know how crypto generates the IV and salt. How are they generated by crypto? If I knew how to generate the salt I could use BouncyCastle's OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator to derive the key and IV.

Comment: The salt is generated and delivered by you with md5 or sha1. The iv is also generated by you, which means if you haven't done that, just skip it.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption/992413#992413

Comment: I tried to use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 but I don't know the salt. Look http://pastebin.com/s34k5jG4. Do I need to extract it from the hexadecimal generated by crypto?

Comment: The IV is only for CBC and not for ASE! And only the first block (16 byte) look different if you use a non-static IV. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29