# Decrypting with same public key used for encryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I have a public key which is used to encrypt some binary data. How can I write the code that can decrypt this data with the same public key ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example

Answer (score 3):

You can't - the whole point about public/private-key-cryptography like RSA is that when you encrypt some data using a public key you can only decrypt it using the matching (!) private key. So without the proper private key you won't be able to recover your AES-key and you won't get back to your cleartext.