# SagePay Form Interation - Guide

Tags: php, forms, opayo

I am trying to integrate the SagePay form integration onto a website. I have read the whole V3.00 documentation on the website/pdf as well as downloaded and installed the FORM integration kit/demo.

The demo works perfectly, but it's not what I am doing. There is no real info about how to use the FORM integration kit.

I have collected the details I need on a form and now have them ready to Encrypt for the CRYPT field on the form to send to SagePay. What function in the integration kit do I need?

Is there a proper basic user guide on there to show you how to use the integration kit?

```
<form method="POST" id="SagePayForm" action="*https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp*">
<input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value= "3.00">
<input type="hidden" name="TxType" value= "50.00">
<input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value= "*YOURVERNODID*">
<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value= "THIS IS WHAT I NEED">
<input type="submit" value="continue to SagePay">
```

How do I go about getting, and decrypting the return CRYPT message too, to process and update a database etc?

I cannot find a good guide on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The V3.0 Documentation only defines the method of encryption (128 bit AES Encryption) that is used and doesn't provide the file or process which are being referenced in the kit.

I had to a little research and found this answer useful for encryption in another thread:
[Java Class for Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419826/3089957)

Following are the summarized steps to be followed in encyprtion:

1. Encrypt string using JAVA class
2. Convert the encrypted string to hex-base( Base 16) text
3. Now, convert this text to Upper case (All caps).