# AES input and output

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, aes

I want an implementation of AES that takes as parameters two String inputs (plaintext, key) and outputs the encrypted String ciphertext. I have search all over the Internet but I haven't found. I have found AES that has byte[] input and outputs String and the other way round. Is it already implemented or I have to play aroundwith Java and create some methods that will finally do the job? 
Thank you!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  The question you should be asking is "*Why* is it that encryption always seems to spit out byte[] ciphertext, not String ciphertext?"  You should be able to find the answer to that question yourself, and when you understand the answer you will understand encryption better.

Comment: Note also that *asking this question at all* suggests you're trying to reinvent a wheel.  Are you **sure** you need to work with AES directly, and not, say, TLS?

Comment: As stated above, there is a reason why AES usually don't get String as an input. If you really want it, then look at a version using byte[] and make the conversion.
@zwol I don't exactly see your point. AES and TLS are two **very** different things, and I see no reason to mistakenly use AES instead of TLS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple java AES encrypt/decrypt example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, ***software library***, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @T.Claverie My point was exactly that they are two very different things. Using a cryptographic *primitive* (e.g. AES) directly, as opposed to using a cryptographic *protocol* (e.g. TLS) that has already addressed all of the next-level-up design issues, is almost always a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

AES encryption produces bytes, which is why you always get bytes out.  What you could use is a separate process to convert the resulting byte array into a string.  The usual way to do this is to use Base64. See the `java.util.Base64` class.

Remember to convert your Base64 string back into a byte array before decrypting.  If you don't then the decryption will fail.

Encryption: plaintext -> encrypt -> bytes -> Base64 string

Decryption: Base64 string -> bytes -> decrypt -> decrypted plaintext