# Encrypt external global properties file in Ready! API

Tags: jenkins, soapui, ready-api

In my project, we store DB passwords in an external Global Properties file and the project is there in git. We use jenkins to execute the builds.
In external global properties file, the password is stored in plain text format. I somehow want to encrypt the file or use any other means to secure it. And I should be able to use that password in scripts to access backend db.
could you please help me out with how do I go about it ? What are the ways?

Thanks

Comment: By default the property value is masked in the UI if the property name contains the keyword `password`. Is that ok?

Comment: we dynamically load values, and for that the properties is stored in .property file (global properties) which is a plain text file. So that wont work :(

Comment: So, that is not the problem of soapui or ready api, right? May be you can use different tools to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example