# Encryption AES 128 with 2 different Result

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'am trying to encrypt a String using AES-128 algorithm with given Key.

Implemented by Java, I used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445878/4646747).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
    String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV

    System.out.println(encrypt(key, initVector, "System")));
}
```

Result:

```
encrypted string: iHvz04u8X7FPo7yagSLthA==
```

The above result is not what I want, I expect `ZJfsFFLjl6YS0Xys5OUVIA==` to be the encrypted value of `System`.

Like the flowing Test On : http://aesencryption.net/

[image]

Any propositions?

Comment: Add the code here not as link

Comment: Where does the two lines Output Comes from, i can only see 1 `System.out.println()

Comment: click on encrypt button one more time, you will see a different result

Comment: You do notice that your Java code is using a random IV, whereas the online version is not using an IV at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman, work for me after removing random IV, thanks for yur solution

Comment: @Kayaman how do i accept your solution since it's a comment ?

Comment: There you go, made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java code is using an IV, while the web based encryption is not using one. For secure purposes, you *should* use a random IV so that encrypting the same data twice with the same key doesn't result in the same ciphertext. But if your requirement is to get the same result as from the web based one, leave out the initialization vector completely.